# Why does URLDecoder.decode() not work properly when I decode URL from non-ASCII into .txt file?

Tags: java, netbeans, exe, urldecode

I tried to decode this url **%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA**, but the result when writing the URL to a *.txt* file was **Кра�?авице-котора�?-нюхала-табак**, including question marks and replacement characters.

However, that only happens when I build my project to an *.exe* file using package as EXE Installer from Netbeans IDE using Inno Setup Compiler, and I run it. The result of decoding the URL yields question marks and replacement characters, but if I run my project from Netbeans 8.2 it works fine; no question marks or replacement characters  are shown in the URL in the *.txt* file. i use java version 1.8.0.

Here is my code

```
File newPath = new File(pathTextField.getText() + "\\" + filename.matcher(sitemapMatcher.group(i)).replaceAll("$2") + "_" + renameFile + ".txt");
FileWriter writeUrl = new FileWriter(newPath);

URL sitemapUrl = new URL(sitemapMatcher.group(i));
URLConnection sitemapUrlConn = sitemapUrl.openConnection();
sitemapUrlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgentArray[randomUserAgent.nextInt(userAgentArray.length)]);
sitemapUrlConn.connect();

BufferedReader sitemapUrlIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sitemapUrlConn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
String sitemapUrlInputLine;

if (clearCheck.isSelected()) {
    while ((sitemapUrlInputLine = sitemapUrlIn.readLine()) != null) {
        final Pattern sitemapUrlPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher sitemapUrlMatcher = sitemapUrlPattern.matcher(sitemapUrlInputLine);

        while (sitemapUrlMatcher.find()) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= sitemapUrlMatcher.groupCount(); j++) {
                if (sitemapUrlMatcher.group(j) != null) {
                    if (regexArray.length > 1 && regexArray.length == replaceArray.length) {
                        final Pattern resultCleanUrl = Pattern.compile(regexArray[0]);
                        if (resultCleanUrl.matcher(sitemapUrlMatcher.group(j)).replaceAll(replaceArray[0]) != null) {
                            tempCleanURL = URLDecoder.decode(resultCleanUrl.matcher(sitemapUrlMatcher.group(j)).replaceAll(replaceArray[0]));
                            for (int indexArray = 1; indexArray < regexArray.length; indexArray++) {
                                if (indexArray + 1 == regexArray.length) {
                                    tempCleanURL = tempCleanURL.replaceAll(regexArray[indexArray], replaceArray[indexArray]);
                                    String cleanUrlSpaceText = tempCleanURL.replaceAll("(\\s+)", " ");
                                    writeUrl.write(cleanUrlSpaceText.trim() + "\n");
                                } else {
                                    tempCleanURL = tempCleanURL.replaceAll(regexArray[indexArray], replaceArray[indexArray]);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            tempCleanURL = URLDecoder.decode(sitemapUrlMatcher.group(j));
                            writeUrl.write(tempCleanURL.trim() + "\n");
                        }
                    } else {
                        final Pattern resultCleanUrl = Pattern.compile(regexArray[0]);
                        if (resultCleanUrl.matcher(sitemapUrlMatcher.group(j)).replaceAll(replaceArray[0]) != null) {
                            tempCleanURL = URLDecoder.decode(resultCleanUrl.matcher(sitemapUrlMatcher.group(j)).replaceAll(replaceArray[0]));
                            writeUrl.write(tempCleanURL.trim() + "\n");
                        } else {
                            tempCleanURL = URLDecoder.decode(sitemapUrlMatcher.group(j));
                            writeUrl.write(tempCleanURL.trim() + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    writeUrl.write("sitemapUrlMatcher[j] null \n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    while ((sitemapUrlInputLine = sitemapUrlIn.readLine()) != null) {
        final Pattern sitemapUrlPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher sitemapUrlMatcher = sitemapUrlPattern.matcher(sitemapUrlInputLine);

        while (sitemapUrlMatcher.find()) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= sitemapUrlMatcher.groupCount(); j++) {
                if (sitemapUrlMatcher.group(j) != null) {
                    tempCleanURL = URLDecoder.decode(sitemapUrlMatcher.group(j));
                    writeUrl.write(tempCleanURL.trim() + "\n");
                } else {
                    writeUrl.write("sitemapUrlMatcher[j] null \n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

writeUrl.flush();
writeUrl.close();
```

This is the incorrect URL which is produced when running the *.exe* file:

[image: Running with exe]

This is the correct URL which is produced when running through Netbeans 8.2:

[image: Running in NetBeans]

Comment: Please post output as *text*, not pictures, and include the URL in question. For one thing, you don't specify the output encoding, which might not be what you think it is. Also please give Java version

Comment: Also, can you say how this .exe is being created and how are you specifying the string in the code?

Comment: Still not quite sure where the cyrillic input is from nor where it's being url-encoded